# One-column figure in a two-column document : top and bottom alignment with text

Tags: floats, captions, vertical-alignment, two-column

I have a tall image in a figure float in a two-column document that I want alone in a single column. I would like the top of the image and the bottom of the figure caption to be both vertically aligned with the text area.

What I do presently is to adjust manually the spacing between the figure and the caption with `\captionsetup{skip=1.5cm}`.

Is there a way to have the `skip` of the figure caption to automatically eat all the remaining vertical space within the column instead of doing it manually?

Here is a MWE to illustrate my problem:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for the MWE
\usepackage{caption, graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!p]
    \captionsetup{skip=1.5cm}
    \centering
    \rule{\columnwidth}{0.9\textheight} % for the MWE
    %\includegraphics[width=1\columnwidth]{my_image} % what I do
    \caption{Some Caption}
\end{figure}
\lipsum % for the MWE
\end{document}
```

Which yields to:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `minipage` with a height of `\textheight`, add a `\vfill` before caption.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for the MWE
\usepackage{caption,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!p]
    %\smallskip   %%if needed
     \begin{minipage}[t][\textheight]{\columnwidth}
    \centering
    \rule{\columnwidth}{0.9\textheight} % for the MWE
    %\includegraphics[height=0.9\textheight, width=\coulmnwidth]{example-image}    

    \vfill    %% leave that blank line above
    \caption{some caption}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum % for the MWE
\end{document}
```

[image]